# Can you use form validation callback in codeigniter when the function is located on different controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let us say I have 2 controllers, the Users controller and the Admin controller. In Users, I am validating a form to check if the user credentials is correct so I created the `callback_confirmUser` function in `form_validation.php` and put the `confirmUser` function in the Users Controller. How can I use this function inside the Admin controller for form validation too?

Comment: where did you place the file ? you must create a helper for this and then load that helper anywhere you want

Comment: Helpers are not meant for that kind of tasks.

Comment: @f4der yes agree. but I'm talking about  possibility and it is possible.

Comment: @karanthakkar There are a lot of ways to achieve it ;) I think the topic starter should go for the best way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to override from the Admin controller. But I don't think that that's the way to go. 
Why don't you create a library for that? It's also possible to extend the CI form validation library in case you miss functionality.
See also: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Good luck!

Edit: it's also possible to use a core controller. You create in the 'core' folder the controller 'MY_Controller.php' that extends the CI_Controller. Instead of extending your controllers from CI_Controller, you extend from MY_Controller. It's than possible to put your validate function in MY_Controller and use it in both admin and user controller.

Comment: `admin` controller ? you mean parent controller right. extending library is a good way though.

Comment: Parent controller? You mean CI_Controller?

Comment: by parent controller i meant exactly the `edit` you have made. ie `cont extends MY_Controller` `MY_Controller extends CI_Controller`

Comment: Ah, at first I left the edit about the parent controller, because I think a library is a slightly better option. Especially when you extend the form validation library.

Comment: thank you for your help guys! I will try creating a library..cheers! :)